# Bigdata analysis in nosql

Tags: cassandra, analytics, nosql-aggregation, bigdata, nosql

I'm trying to migrate our postgres database containing millions of clicks (few years click history) to more performing system. Our current analytic queries, which are running on postgres are taking forever to complete and it degrades performance of the whole database. I've been investigating possible solutions and I've decided to closely investigate 2 options:

- HBase with Hadoop (mapreduce)
- Cassandra with Spark

I was working with NoSQL before, however never used it for analytical purposes. At first I was a bit disapointed how little analytical query options those databases provide (missing groupBy, count, ...). After reading many articles and presentations I've found out, that I need to design my schema according how I intend to read my data and that storage layer is separated from query layer. Which adds more redundant data, however in the world of NoSQL this is not an issue.

Eventually I've found one nice grails plugin [cassandra-orm](https://grails.org/plugin/cassandra-orm), which internally encapsulates orderBy feature in cassandra counters [counters](http://bflorian.github.io/cassandra-orm/guide/2%20Key%20Concepts.html#2.4%20Counters). However I'm still worried about howto make this design extendable. What about the queries, that will come in the future, which I have no clue about today, how can I design my schema prepared for that ?
One option would be to use Spark, but Spark doesn't provide data in real time.

Could you give me some insight or advice what are the best possible options for bigdata analysis. Should I use combination of real time queries vs. pre-aggregated ones?

Thanks,

Comment: Hi Tomas, can you add right tags to this question? Hbase, Spark are missing. nosql and nosql-aggregation may be duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

1. If you are looking at near real time data analysis, **Spark + HBase** combination is one of the solutions.
2. If you want to compromise on throughput, **Solr + Cassandra** combination from Datastax can be used.

I am using **Solr + Cassandra** from Datastax for my use case, which does not require real time processing. The performance of search option is not that great with this combo but I am OK with the throughput.

**Spark+HBase** combination seems to be promising. Depending on your business requirement & expertise, you can chose the right combination.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the ability to analyse data in near-real-time with complete flexibility in query structure, I think your best bet would be to throw a scalable indexing engine such as **Elasticsearch** or **Solr** into your polyglot persistence mix. You could still use Cassanra as the primary data store and then index those fields you're interested in querying and/or aggregating.

Have a look at [Datastax Enterprise](http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.0/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchIntro.html) which bundles together Cassandra and Solr. Also have a look at Solr's [Stats component](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Stats+Component) and its [faceting](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Faceting) capabilities. These, combined with the indexing engine's rich query language, are handy for implementing many analytics use cases.

If your data set consists of a few million records 'only', I think you'll be able to get some good response times from Solr or ES on a reasonably spec'ed cluster.